# Converting tuple from a list

Tags: python, string

I am having trouble converting a list into a tuple.

```
student = ['1712 Albert', '1703 Benny', '1799 Henry']
```

I want it to be

```
[(1712, 'Albert'), (1703, 'Benny'), (1799, 'Henry')]
```

So far I've done this

```
list1 = []
for elements in student:
    list1.append(tuple(elements.split(" ")))
```

However I'm getting the output:

```
[('1712', 'Albert'), ('1703', 'Benny'), ('1799', 'Henry')]
```

Which is not the same as the one above. How do I get rid of the quote marks for the numbers only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to convert the first element to an integer explicitly:

```
list1 = []
for elements in student:
    id_, name = elements.split(None, 1)
    list1.append((int(id_), name))
```

I've updated the `str.split()` call a little: `None` tells the command to split on *any whitespace*, no matter how many characters (this includes tabs and newlines). The `1` tells `str.split()` to split just *once*, leaving whitespace in names in-tact. So `"1703 Albert Ben"` would become `(1703, 'Albert Ben')` in the output.

Demo:

```
>>> student = ['1712 Albert', '1703 Benny', '1799 Henry']
>>> list1 = []
>>> for elements in student:
...     id_, name = elements.split(None, 1)
...     list1.append((int(id_), name))
...
>>> list1
[(1712, 'Albert'), (1703, 'Benny'), (1799, 'Henry')]
```

Comment: I cant have 2 arguments inside append(). Also it must be in a tuple

Comment: @a_student: there is just *one* argument inside `list.append()` however. It's a tuple, `(..., ...)`. Note the extra parentheses!

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this one-line solution

```
student = ['1712 Albert', '1703 Benny', '1799 Henry']
list1 = [ (int(year),name ) for year,name in [ x.split(" ") for x in student ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = []
for elements in student:
    year, name = elements.split(" ", 1)
    list1.append((int(year), name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The quote marks are there because the numbers you have are in the format of a string. you need to change them into int().

```
l=[]
for element in list:
    i=element.split(' ')
    z=tuple(int(i[0]),i[1])
    l.append(z)
```

Comment: The `tuple` part is redundant; just using the comma makes it a tuple already.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code like this, to turn first element into a integer and then process them into a tuple.

```
for elements in student: 
    split_elements = elements.split(" ")
    split_elements[0] = int(split_elements[0])
    list1.append(tuple(split_elements))
```

Another approach would be running an additional loop to achieve so, but, both soes the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

another one line solution:

```
student = ['1712 Albert', '1703 Benny', '1799 Henry']    
list(map(lambda x:tuple(map(lambda y:int(y) if y.isnumeric() else y,x.split())),student))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
split_lists = [data.split(" ") for data in student]

students_list = [tuple([int(data[0]), data[1]]) for data in split_lists]

print(students_list)
```

You just need to convert a number string into an integer. If you are not always confident that the converted string is a number, you can populate the `students_list` using `try-except` when converting into `int()`, like so:

```
students_list = list()

for data in split_lists:
    sub_list = list()
    try:
        sub_list.append(int(data[0]))
    except ValueError:
        sub_list.append(data[0])
    sub_list.append(data[1])
    students_list.append(tuple(sub_list))

print(students_list)
```